# How or where are predefined attribute declared or define in VHDL langague

Tags: vhdl

There are signal attributes for detecting edges like
`'LAST_VALUE` or `'EVENT` as shown in code below:

```
FUNCTION rising_edge  (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
  RETURN (s'EVENT AND (To_X01(s) = '1') AND
                      (To_X01(s'LAST_VALUE) = '0'));
END;
```

How is the `'LAST_VALUE` attribute defined so that it can get the last value of a signal? Or where are these kinds of predefined attributes defined? Is there a file or library?

Comment: but there is definition of rising_edge function and it is predefined function but its not part of VHDL language.and then how this predefined attribute can be part of VHDL language?see BIT is predefined type but we can get its definition and its not part of VHDL construct. syntax,keywords are part of language but how come attributes become part of language if it would have been than it would be key word in VHDL?

Answer (score 1):

These attributes are defined in the language itself. The language is defined by the IEEE 1076-2008 standard. It's called [Language Reference Manual (LRM)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4772740).

The mentioned attributes are defined in LRM 16.2:

> **16.2 Predefined attributes**
>
> Predefined attributes denote values, functions, types, subtypes, signals, and ranges associated with various kinds of named entities. These attributes are described as follows. For each attribute, the following information is provided:
>
> - The kind of attribute: value, type, subtype, range, function, or signal
> - The prefixes for which the attribute is defined
> - A description of the parameter or argument, if one exists
> - The result of evaluating the attribute, and the result type (if applicable)
> - Any further restrictions or comments that apply
>
> For those predefined attributes that denote functions, the functions do not have named formal parameters; therefore, named association (see 6.5.7.1) cannot be used when invoking a function denoted by a predefined attribute.

The attributes for signals are listed in LRM 16.2.4:

> **16.2.4 Predefined attributes of signals**
>
> ...
>
> ```
> S'EVENT        Kind:        Function.
>                Prefix:      Any signal denoted by the static signal name S.
>                Result type: Type BOOLEAN.
>                Result:      A value that indicates whether an event has just
>                             occurred on signal S.
>                             Specifically:
>                For a scalar signal S, S'EVENT returns the value TRUE if an event
>                has occurred on S during the current simulation cycle; otherwise,
>                it returns the value FALSE.
>
>                For a composite signal S, S'EVENT returns TRUE if an event has
>                occurred on any scalar subelement of S during the current simulation
>                cycle; otherwise, it returns FALSE.
>
> S'LAST_VALUE   Kind:        Function
>                Prefix:      Any signal denoted by the static signal name S.
>                Result type: The base type of S.
>                Result:      For a signal S, if an event has occurred on S in any
>                             simulation cycle, S'LAST_VALUE returns the value of S
>                             prior to the update of S in the last simulation cycle
>                             in which an event occurred; otherwise, S'LAST_VALUE
>                             returns the current value of S.
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: but i need source code of LAST_VALUE attribute so where i can get that source code ?can you tell me  please?

Comment: There is no source code. It's defined in the language itself. The LRM defines how a vendor has to implement these attributes in his tools. Even `rising_edge` is mostly not implemented as defined in ieee package. Most vendors use their own optimized native version.

Comment: but there is definition of rising_edge function and it is predefined function but its not part of VHDL language.and then how this predefined attribute can be part of VHDL language?see BIT is predefined type but we can get its definition and its not part of VHDL construct. syntax,keywords are part of language but  how come attributes become part of language if it would have been than it would be key word in VHDL.

Comment: Attributes are something like context sensitive reserved words. `rising_edge` and BIT are also part of the LRM, because the LRM defines a) the library `std` and in addition a set of basic packages like for `std_logic`. VHDL is an old language, so there is no clean line between the language and the "core library" / "runtime library". This will change with my [latest initiative](https://github.com/VHDL).

Comment: rising_edge and BIT can be part of LRM but these are not part of VHDL language. but keywords like signal,if,else,while,process and many more are part of VHDL language and part of VHDL compiler. and BIT and rising_edge and all are part of library but whose part these predefined attribute are like i did one experiment in which a = b'LAST_VALUE so i got not of b in a. so is these attributes are part of VHDL compiler or library?